# How to select with joins and only return rows from one table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database which looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vigdL.png

I want to select all rooms which don't have any reservation for a given time period.

Here is what I tried:

```
SELECT idRoom, type, beds FROM Room r
INNER JOIN Reservation_has_Room has on r.idRoom = has.Room_idRoom
INNER JOIN Rezervation re on has.Reservation_has_Room = re.idReservation
 WHERE (re.checkIn<'2019-06-04'
 AND re.checkOut<'2019-06-01') 
 or
(re.checkIn>'2019-06-04'
 AND re.CheckOut>'2019-06-01');
```

But this script returns a room every time it finds a reservation which is not overlapping the date.

## edit:

I think I might be misunderstood.
This is the case:
In Rooms i have this records:

```
 idRoom, type, beds
'1', 'Standard', '1'
'2', 'Standard', '1'
```

### Reservation:

```
 idReservation, checkIn, checkOut
'1', '2019-05-22', '2019-06-03'
'2', '2021-05-22', '2021-06-03'
'3', '2022-05-22', '2022-06-03'
```

### Reservation_has_Room

```
 Reservation_idReservation, Room_idRoom
'1', '1'
'2', '1'
'3', '1'
```

So as you can see for room nr 1 I have 3 reservation. One is overlapping and rest are not. In this case, the script from @AlexYes returns this:

```
 idRoom, type, beds
'1', 'Standard', '1'
'1', 'Standard', '1'
'2', 'Standard', '1'
```

So it returns room number one, even two times.
My expected result is :

```
 idRoom, type, beds
'2', 'Standard', '1'
```

So only room nr 2 is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `not exists`:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM Room r
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Reservation_has_Room rhr INNER JOIN 
                       Rezervation re
                       ON rhr.Reservation_has_Room = re.idReservation

                  WHERE r.idRoom = rhr.Room_idRoom AND
                        re.checkIn <= '2019-06-04' AND
                        re.checkOut >= '2019-06-01'
                 );
```

The logic for the overlaps is simple  If someone checks in one or before the last date *and* checks out on or after the first day, then there is an overlap and the room is not available.

This accounts for all the possible ways the intervals could overlap.  Note that this includes the all four days; you might or might not want to include the first and last days depending on your rules for check in/check out.

Comment: YES! This is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is the overlapping range problem, and your `WHERE` clause should be:

```
WHERE
    re.checkIn <= '2019-06-04' AND
    re.checkOut >= '2019-06-01'
```

Your full query:

```
SELECT
    idRoom,
    type,
    beds
FROM Room r
INNER JOIN Reservation_has_Room has
    ON r.idRoom = has.Room_idRoom
INNER JOIN Rezervation re
    ON has.Reservation_has_Room = re.idReservation
WHERE
    re.checkIn <= '2019-06-04' AND
    re.checkOut >= '2019-06-01';
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does because you're doing an inner join and filter the reservations. What you need is rooms left join reservations on the time period conditions and then filter units that don't have any reservations joined:

```
SELECT idRoom, type, beds 
FROM Room r
LEFT JOIN ( -- subquery that returns reservation business entities filtered by your time period
    SELECT *
    FROM Reservation_has_Room has
    JOIN Rezervation re
    ON has.Reservation_has_Room = re.idReservation
    WHERE (re.checkIn <= '2019-06-01' AND re.checkOut >= '2019-06-04') -- (1)
    OR re.checkIn between '2019-06-01' and '2019-06-04' -- (2)
    OR re.checkOut between '2019-06-01' and '2019-06-04' -- (3)
) rr
ON r.idRoom = rr.Room_idRoom
WHERE rr.checkIn is null -- filter out units that don't have matching reservations
```

the reservations are first filtered by the 3 cases:

1) fully overlapping reservations
2) reservations that start somewhere in the middle of the period and end some time after
3) reservations that start some time before and end somewhere in the middle of the period

The condition suggested by Tim might also work. But the main point is to switch to `LEFT JOIN` with range filter in the join condition and have `WHERE re.checkIn is null`

To make your solution more dynamic, you would use subqueries to specify the time bounds just once and reuse these values in the filter:

```
WITH
 start_date as (select '2019-06-01'::date)
,end_date as (select '2019-06-04'::date)
```

and have this as a join condition:

```
(
    re.checkIn <= (select * from start_date) AND re.checkOut >= (select * from end_date) -- (1)
    or re.checkIn between (select * from start_date) and (select * from end_date) -- (2)
    or re.checkOut between (select * from start_date) and (select * from end_date) -- (3)
)
```

Comment: Thank you, but if there are more reservation on the same room, this script returns duplicated rows.

Comment: I am confused. Does the @klagu wants to find rooms that ARE NOT booked or the booked ones

Comment: @ninjabber I'm looking for a non booked rooms.

Comment: @klagu but you filter out reservations here, are you sure? also, can you have records in `Reservation_has_Room` table that don't have matching records in `Rezervation`? if so you can add another filter, like `WHERE re.checkIn is null AND has.id is null`

Comment: No there are no records in Reservation_has_Room that don't match reservation. 
To specify my question:
This scripts returns a room every time it finds a reservation that is not overlapping. So if there are 10 non overlapping reservations, it will return 10 records.

Comment: I understand you. That's what I tried to do but looks like it still returns records because it joins the entire `Reservation_has_Room`. I've edited the script so it first joins `Reservation_has_Room` and `Rezervation` in a subquery and then does what I described above. This way I suppose it will work properly. Let me know!

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that you need only 2 tables here. Properties of rooms and properties of reservations. If a room is in the reservations table than it has a reservation obviously. so:

```
room_id start_date end_date
 1       s_d1        e_d1 
 1       s_d2        e_d2
 2       s_d3        e_d3
```

you want to find room_id's of the customer's date range that is not booked. (normally till 12 pm)

cust_s_d NOT BETWEEN s_d and e_d or 
cust_e_d NOT BETWEEN s_d and e_d

```
select room_id from reservations 
where
cust_s_d NOT BETWEEN s_d and e_d
AND 
cust_e_d NOT BETWEEN s_d and e_d;
```

join the result with the room's properties and thats it.